# Uploading and displaing an image using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX, where I have written a code that contains `display Image`, through I want to display the image on my scene, but it's not working. The image doesn't display.
When I'm using the `getAbsolutePath()` it also displays an error. Although 70% of my coding is done, I'm just stuck with displaying images on the scene (without uploading it).
Here is the code I'm working with:

```
package application;
    
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class Main extends Application {
    
    public ImageView iv;
    private GridPane gridpane;
 
    
//Image
    Image img = new Image("application/PA_Image.jpg");
    


    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            

//Upload Image Button
            final Button button  = new Button("Display Image");  
            
//FileChooser
            final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();


            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                File selectedFile  = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                 if (selectedFile != null) { 
                     System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                      
                     Image image = new Image(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
                     iv = new ImageView(image);
                     
                     //Image uploadedImage = new Image(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                     
                 }
            });
            
            final StackPane stac = new StackPane();
            stac.getChildren().add(button);

            Scene scene = new Scene(stac,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

So, what I need, is to display images on my scene by clicking the button and selecting an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Image()` constructor expects a `URI` and not an Absolute path.
There are two ways to approach this.

1. Turn your `absolutePath` in a `URI` by adding the required prefix `file://`
2. Use `InputStream` which holds the Image data and you don't have to care about the Path after it has been created. I like this way better.

Example:

```java
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    File selectedFile  = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

        final InputStream targetStream; // Creating the InputStream
        try
        {
            targetStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile));
            Image image = new Image(targetStream);
            iv = new ImageView(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

There are also some other problems with your code.

1. Create your `ImageView` and initialize it. Not when the button is clicked but right at the beginning
2. Add the `ImageView` to your `Scene`
3. Do not create new `ImageView` every time the button is clicked, just change the Image.

This is my code based on yours:

```java
public ImageView iv = new ImageView();
private GridPane gridpane;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
try {


    //Upload Image Button
    final Button button = new Button("Display Image");

    //FileChooser
    final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();


    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        if (selectedFile != null) {

            final InputStream targetStream;
            try {
                targetStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile));
                Image image = new Image(targetStream);
                iv.setImage(image); // Set Image

            } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    final StackPane stac = new StackPane();
    stac.getChildren().add(button);
    stac.getChildren().add(iv); // Add ImageView

    Scene scene = new Scene(stac, 1600, 800);
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping your stream in `DataInputStream`?. Also, it's better to keep the scope as narrow as possible, if `targetStream` is not used outside the `try-catch` block, then you should keep it inside that block.

Comment: Also, instead of commenting `//Upload Image Button` on `button`, it's more clear if you call your button `uploadButton`.